# What is meant with 騒音 here?

Tags: words

ビルの工事の騒音で、電話がよく聞こえません。
=>"With the noise of the multi-floor buildings construction work, you can't hear the phonecall well."

What is meant with "noise" here? I guess it is the interference of the steel constructions with the radiowaves of the mobilephone?
Since there is no 携帯電話 here and since there is no explicite reference to noise in sense of interference with electromagnetic waves, I wanted to ask for your opinion. It seems very unlikely to me that actual sonic noise caused by the buildings structure is meant. Because in that case, I would assume that the building is about to collapse...^^

Answer (score 5):

This 騒音 isn't electric noise. It means noise of building a building. For example, the sound of hammering something, heavy machines working and construction workers speaking loudly, etc.